# How to adjust ImageDraw opacity over main image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I created a drawing by ImageDraw module, but I didn't calibrate opacity of this drawing.

What I want to say that I used ImageDraw for to create gradient map. Then, I used functions of ImageChops for to combine with original photograph. There isn't any problem with codes. My codes work, but gradient map which was created has very intensive colours. I want to calibrate opacity of that. My problem is that.

Code structure following

```
class Affects(object):
  def __init__(self,rect,type):
    ...
    #'poppy' : [(252,170,11),(205,62,110),(129,2,45)]
    self.img = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (self.imgx, self.imgy), (255,255,255))
    self.draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(self.img)
    ...

  def do_chops(self,main,*args):
    if args[0] == 'blend' or args[0] == 'composite':
      return getattr(PIL.ImageChops,str(args[0]))(main,self.img,args[1])
    else:
      return getattr(PIL.ImageChops,str(args[0]))(main,self.img)

  ....

  def poppy(self,main,*args):
    grd = libgrd.Gradient(self.maps['poppy'],self.rect)
    grd.draw(self.type,self.draw)
    return self.do_chops(main,*args)

class MyApp(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.img = PIL.Image.open('iam.jpg').resize((640,640))
    ...

  def __poppy(self):
    Affects(libgrd.Rect(0, 0, 640, 640),'hz').poppy(self.img,'lighter').save('test.jpg')
```

How can I do this operation ?

Comment: Please post your solution in the answer box below, it'll help others.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is below;

```
class Affects(object):
    ...

    def poppy(self,main,*args):
        ...
        enh = ImageEnhance.Brightness(self.img)
        self.img = enh.enhance(0.7)
        ...
```